# PHP Email says it sent, but when I open my inbox there is no message

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create a contact us form in jquery, ajax, and php. when i click the button in html jquery and ajax make the request to php and then i use the php mail() function to send the email. however, when i click "send" it says everything is ok and the ajax function success function runs alerting the user the message was sent. now, when i go to the inbox where it is supposed to be sent i don't get any email. i am running this on windows 7, ecowebhost.

here is the html form;

```
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "js/callmail.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app = "">

            <div class = "container">

    <form name = "contact">

        <label for = "subject" class = "control-label">Subject:</label>
        <input name = "subject" id = "subject" ng-model = "subject" required/>
        <span class = "warning" ng-show="contact.subject.$touched && contact.subject.$invalid">You Must Enter a subject!</span>
        <span class = "success" ng-show="contact.subject.$touched && contact.subject.$valid">Valid!</span>

        <br/>

        <label for = "body" class = "control-label">Body:</label>
        <input name = "body" id = "body" ng-model = "body" required/>
        <span class = "warning" ng-show="contact.body.$touched && contact.body.$invalid">Your email must have a body!</span>
        <span class = "success" ng-show="contact.body.$touched && contact.body.$valid">Valid!</span>

        <br/>

        <label for = "signature" class = "control-label">Return Email:</label>
        <input name = "signature" id = "signature" ng-model = "signature" type = "email" required/>
        <span class = "warning" ng-show="contact.signature.$touched && contact.signature.$invalid">You must enter a valid return email!</span>
        <span class = "success" ng-show="contact.signature.$touched && contact.signature.$valid">Valid!</span>

        <br/>

        <button ng-disabled = "contact.$invalid" id = "sendmail" type = "submit" class = "btn btn-success">Submit</button>

    </form>
```

here is the ajax and jquery:

```
$(function() {
$("#sendmail").click(function() {

    var data = {

        to: "tyler.psu.grim@gmail.com",
        subject: $("#signature").val() + ": " + $("#subject").val(),
        message: $("#body").val(),
    };

    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "email.php",
        data: data,
        success: function() {

            alert("Message sent");

        }

    });

    console.log(data);

});

});
```

and here is the php code:

```
<?php   
    if ($_POST["submit"]) { 


        $subject = $_POST["subject"];
        $message = $_POST["body"];
        $headers = "Reply to: " . $_POST["signature"];

        mail("tyler.psu.grim@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $headers); 

    }

?>
```

Very new to each of these languages so i have absolutely no idea where to go from here.

Comment: Is the PHP actually doing anything? I cannot see a `submit` POST variable so `if ($_POST["submit"])` is always false.

Comment: would the button not serve as the submit POST variable?

Comment: It might do, but since you are posting with Ajax, you craft the `data` and are not including it.

Comment: you aren't verifying that `mail()` succeeds or replying back to ajax with a conditional response. Also don't seem to have a `from` which is a requirement for any email

Comment: how do i include it? and does it need a from?

Comment: in the headers and I don't think an email can be sent without one. There would be nothing to show in an inbox otherwise. `reply to` is not the same thing

Comment: @charlietfl `from` can be set in php.ini config file.

Comment: Yes `from` headers are required according to the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: @KimberlyW Keep reading that page: *When sending mail, the mail must contain a From header. This can be set with the additional_headers parameter, or a default can be set in php.ini.*

Comment: @DavidG still needs to be set somewhere and my guess is OP has no idea how to set it in a config

Comment: @charlietfl Agreed, but I don't think that is the issue here (or at least not the main one)

Comment: how do i include the "submit" so the php sees it and evaluates it to "true"?

Comment: Why do you want to include submit? Just remove the `if` check.

Comment: @DavidG certainly one of them. Others would be incorrect keys in `$_POST`. @Tyler the keys for data sent don't match what you are trying to receive

Comment: @charlietfl Exactly, that was my first comment which OP seems to be ignoring :/

Comment: when i remove the if check i get the email, but it is blank. i get the subject but the body is blank. and the headers say Reply to: but does not include the return email?

Comment: Well you post a value with key `message` and refer to it in PHP as `body`. Seriously, you need to take more care with your code and actually try to understand what is going on here.

Comment: Tyler you are sending `to,subject, message` but looking for `signature,subject,body`. Before you take another step start reading up on how to check errors on both ends

Answer (score -2):

```
$(function() {
$("#sendmail").click(function() {
    var to = "tyler.psu.grim@gmail.com";
    var subject = $("#signature").val() +": " + $("#subject").val(); //?? WHERE IS SUBJECT INPUT????
    var message = $("#body").val(); 
    var signature = $("#signature").val();

    var data = {

        to: to,
        subject: subject,
        message: message,
        signature: signature
    };

    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "email.php",
        data: data,
        success: function(msg) {

            console.log(msg);

        }

    });

    console.log(data);
    return false;
});
});
```

/////

```
if(isset($_POST["subject"])) {
    $subject = $_POST["subject"];
    $message = $_POST["body"];
    $headers = "Reply to: " . $_POST["signature"];

    if(!mail("tyler.psu.grim@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $headers)) {
        echo 'something is wrong';
    } else {
        echo 'nothing is wrong';
    }


}
```

And you might want to check the spam folder as well.
Are you sending from localhost or your own website?
Some webserver software such as xampp do not allow/execute? this mail function by default.

Comment: there is no echo when i do this? (nothing happens)

Comment: and i am running it from from own website on ecowebhost

Comment: You won't see an echo on the page. It is an AJAX call so you would see it as a response to the request. Try viewing the response in the Browser's Web Console.

Comment: that `contentType` makes no sense

Comment: See my edit, i added a return false so the page won't reload after hitting submit.

Comment: You can edit this post as much as you like but you are fundamentally wrong with your answer here.

Comment: This answer only scratches the surface of all the problems

Comment: And the fact that he isn't sending the submit post therefore it isn't working at all